# Python, Tkinter, can only view partial GUI when called from another window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is the GUI code which is actually run from another file. It calls two other Python files and executes a function from those files. The files are scan.py and webcam.py. The function from scan.py is `alz_scan()` and the function from webcam.py is `TakeSnapAndSave()`.

It works fine executing those functions but the problem is I cannot see the background Image and the status bar which I coded here.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import scan
import webcam



def needTodo1():
    scan.alz_scan()
def needTodo2():
    webcam.TakeSnapAndSave()
def alz():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('........')

# ******** MAIN MENU  ******** #

    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    root.minsize(700, 600)
    root.geometry("600x500")

    subMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
    subMenu.add_command(label="Capture", command=needTodo2)
    subMenu.add_command(label="Load", command=needTodo1)
    subMenu.add_separator()
    subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

# *********** Toolbar ************ #

    toolbar = Frame(root, bg="blue")

    insertBar = Button(toolbar, text="Capture", command=needTodo2)
    insertBar.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=2, pady=2)

    insertBar = Button(toolbar, text="Load", command=needTodo1)
    insertBar.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=2, pady=2)

    #insertBar = Button(toolbar, text="HOME", command=needTodo)
    #insertBar.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)


    toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)



# ********* IMAGE BACKGROUND ************ #

    canvas = Canvas(root, width=699, height=837, bg='white')
    canvas.pack()
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file='/home/bot/Desktop/environments/my_env/img.gif')
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=gif1, anchor=NW)



# ********* STATUS BAR ************ #

    status = Label(root, text="It is ready to work....", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your most up-to-date code? Because it just gives me `NameError: name 'needTodo' is not defined`

Comment: My bad....edited

Comment: Ok, now when I run it I can see both the image and the toolbar. Granted, I have to expand the window so that it's a little taller than 837 pixels, but it's there.

Comment: I can't see it. I have made the canvas smaller to 600 by 600...and I see a white background where the background image is supposed to be. But can't find the image.And I have given the image path correctly. Can't find the status bar either

Comment: Tested on my side and the image is shown. Have you check to make sure the link is good? I think maybe your problem is when you press the buttons and are trying to load another image? If this is the case then we will need some example code for both your imports. You problem might be in `alz_scan()` or `TakeSnapAndSave()`.